# The package system is broken when trying to install updates

Tags: updates, package-management

When I try to install updates with update manager I get this message

```
The package system is broken

Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.

Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: `apt-get install -f`

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libc6-dev:i386: Depends: libc6 (= 2.15-0ubuntu10) but 2.15-0ubuntu10 is installed
                Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.15-0ubuntu10) but 2.15-0ubuntu10 is installed
```

And when i type in `apt-get install -f` I get this answer

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

What to do?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install -f` (this gives you "root" permissions)

Answer (score 1):

To get root permission use `sudo` and then the command, like this >> 
`sudo apt-get update` OR `sudo apt-get upgrade` OR in your case you have to use `sudo apt-get install -f`.

By the way if you get an error when you type in the `sudo apt-get update` command regarding `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` run this command `sudo killall apt-get` and if you still get the error, then run this command `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock` and you should be able to update successfully the next time you try `sudo apt-get update`

Hope it helped :)